# Is the cable pull of Shimano GRX FD-RX400 same as the one of 10- or 11-speed road groups?

Tags: shimano, compatibility, derailleur-front, road

What is the required cable pull for FD-RX400?

AFAIK Shimano road 11-speed front deraileurs require the same (larger) cable pull, while 10- and fewer-speed FDs expect lower one (with exception of Tiagra 4700, which uses the "11-speed" pull).

Does 10-speed GRX belong to either camp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

11 speed GRX 810 and 600 are compatible with 9000, 8000, 7000, 6800, 5800 etc. 11 speed road groups - so it obviously uses the 11 speed cable pull ratio.

10 speed GRX 400 is compatible with the Tiagra 4700 10 speed road group only, so it uses the ‘11 speed’ 
cable pull ratio as well.

Shimano is nice enough to publish very comprehensive (if complicated) compatibility info: https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?cid=C-453&acid=C-454.

Look for *Drivetrain for ROAD, Gravel/Adventure, URBAN (METREA) components* then *Rear drivetrain compatibility* and 
*Front drivetrain compatibility*.

Comment: AFAIK tiagra 10 speed was not the same as any other 10 shimano speed.  Does that apply to tiagra 11 speed ?

Comment: @Criggie there is no 11 Speed Tiagra https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/lc/tiagra/3x10, or rather 11 speed Tiagra is called '105' :-)

Comment: Ahh ok - does para2 have a typo and should say 10 speed not 11 speed  ?

Comment: Does that mean that one can install FD-RX400, FC-RX600 46-30 10speed and pair it up with ultegra 11speed cassette with 11 speed RD-RX810?

Answer (score 3):

4700 now has a friend. The 10-speed GRX is the same deal.

Typically compact-friendly road FDs can handle 46-30 without issue, so this shouldn't be a huge deal in the scheme of things.